# Python string being outputted on multiple lines when scraping html with selenium | Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to scrape a string from a website and store it in a variable in python using selenium. Here is what the html looks like:

```
<span fxlayout="" fxlayoutalign="center center" class="height-100 current" dataaftercontent="" 

style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <!----> 3  ×<!----><!----><!---->
    <span class="part missing bg-accent-5 ng-star-inserted">
    <span class="question-mark">?
    </span>
    </span><!----><!----><!----><!----><span class="part ng-star-inserted">=</span> 24 <!----><!----></span>
```

When I scrape this and store it in a python string and print it out this is what i get:

```
3 ×
?
=
15
```

I want to have something like this outputted however:

```
3 x ? = 15
```

Here is the code I am using to scrape and print this out:

```
problemStr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ttr-root/ttr-root-app/div/div/section/ttr-garage/ttr-game-holder/div/div/div[1]/ttr-game-footpedal/section[2]/section/section/ttr-game-question/span[2]").text
print(problemStr)
```

How could I achieve a neat line of text instead of a multi line one? I have tried to use `"".join(problemStr.splitlines())` to create a single line output but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired result by using Replace method of String class in python. Based on HTML DOM provided I used below code

```
    problemStr = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text.replace("\n"," ") 
# I replaced each new line with space
    print(problemStr)
```

**Result:**
3 × ? = 24